# Struts2 raising type conversion errors for specific types only

Tags: java, struts2

We have a custom type converter registered in our app, lets say `FooTypeConverter`, which is responsible for converting to and from type `Foo`. We are not interested in type conversion errors of other types, but we would want to raise a validation error if a type conversion of a target type `Foo` fails. We are interested in both `String`=>`Foo` and `Foo`=>`String`

I know this can be achieved with a  `ConversionErrorFieldValidator`, but this means decorating the target fields. Is there any way that we can achieve this with some global setup?

Thanks and best regards,
Asa

Comment: you can check it for per field basis even check http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-TypeConversionErrorHandling

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi, exactly that's what I want to avoid if possible. The conversion error field validator has to be set on a per field basis. What I want to do is to have some sort of global setup, so all conversion errors of target type FOO are raised.

Comment: In this case i am afraid that Struts2 is providing such thing as the error handling mechanism been developed as a generic, might be you need to cater this by some sort of custom interceptor.Might be some one has better idea if this is possible or not or per case basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nutshell:** Replace the default `"conversionError"` interceptor and replace it with a version that overrides `shouldAddError` that returns `true` iff the value's type is `Foo`.

**Details:** The default interceptor is an extension of XWork's `ConversionErrorInterceptor` that mostly checks values. It also checks for a specific type, so I think this is the cleanest hook. Override `shouldAddError` and return `true` iff the value type is the one you're interested in.

Roughly:

```
protected boolean shouldAddError(String propertyName, Object value) {
    return value instanceOf Foo;
}
```

You may wish to retain some of the value checks, so double-check. It might be easiest to call `super.shouldAddError` first, and do your check iff it returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dave. This will catch Foo=>String conversion errors, but what about String=>Foo? (Sorry, maybe my question was not clear enough. I'll update that)

Comment: @Asa Not sure, I'd have to play a bit to see what actually happens. In any case, AFAICT, a custom interceptor is about the only real solution, whether it's based on name or type, or you'd need to add some additional info to help identify the errors you're specifically interested in.

Comment: I took this approach, and added extra info to the context from the `FooTypeConverter` which I used in the new custom interceptor to determine whether to raise the error or not. Since the property name was not available in the type converter, I used the key `XWorkConverter.CONVERSION_PROPERTY_FULLNAME` to get hold of the same from the context. Thanks again for the help Dave.

Comment: @Asa Ah, interesting--cool. I'll look in to this and see if there's a good way to make this functionality generic or injectible, although I think it's pretty niche. Glad you worked it out.

Comment: Yeah, it would have been cool to make this work in a better way, since IMHO, adding the extra information to the context should not really be a responsibility of the type converter. Anyway, it's a niche case as you say, and I've got a working solution :)